# shouldn't the Costas loop remove/add a sample in certain circumstances?

Tags: gnuradio

I'm new to GnuRadio and signal processing. I'm trying to understand the Costas Loop.
Looking at its source code, I see that it consistently generates the same number of output samples as it receives at its input.

However, if the clock used for signal sampling runs slightly faster than the clock responsible for generating the signal, it implies that over the same period, it will produce slightly more samples compared to a scenario where the clocks are perfectly synchronized.
Shouldn't the Costas Loop eliminate these extra samples?

Answer (score -1):

The Costas loop is not a sample clock recovery tool. It's for recovering frequency and phase.

So, no. It should never insert samples!

Inserting samples would also be a very crude way of dealing with this, because you'd get all kinds of sudden jumps in errors.

What you want in that case is a timing recovery loop, as for example implemented by the Symbol Sync block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that still doesn't clarify it for me.
What is the output of the Costas loop? I thought it is a set of samples as if it was sampled by the sending system, that means at regular intervals.

Comment: The costas loop corrects the phase of samples, not the sampling clock offset. That's where the difference between your expectation and what a Costas loop does lies!

Comment: sorry, still did not answer my question: is the output of the Costas loop supposed to be equivalent with the original clock sampling the signal?
When you have an array of samples, there is a knowledge of the sampling frequency so every sample has an implicit timestamp. What are the timestamps of the samples coming out of the Costas loop? And measured by which clock?

Comment: So my understanding is that when you sample a signal you get a series of samples, each sample consists of two numbers I and Q. But due to the known sampling frequency each sample has a third property which is the timestamp (relative to the start of the sampling). What is the timestamp of the samples coming out of the Costas loop?

Comment: The sampling instants are unchanged. I will not repeat a fourth time: it is not a Costas loop's job to even try and tackle sampling clock offset.